# $(0,2)$ worldsheet SUSY implies ${\cal N}=1$ spacetime SUSY (reference request)

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, specific-reference, superconformality

In [1] they write that

> "Boucher et al. [14] found quite generally that $(0, 2)$ world-sheet SUSY ensures the existence of $N = 1$ spacetime SUSY."

But this reference "[14]" they cite just says: "W. Boucher, D. Friedan, A. Kent, S.H. Shenker and E. Witten, in preparation". I did not find a paper with these authors, but it is hard without knowing the title or the magazine/journal.

Does anyone know what paper they are referring to?

---

[1] Banks, Thomas, et al. "Phenomenology and conformal field theory or can string theory predict the weak mixing angle?." Nuclear Physics B 299.3 (1988): 613-626.

Comment: FWIW, [googling](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=boucher+friedan+kent+shenker+witten) reveals that other references refer to the sought-for paper [14] as either _in preparation_ or _unpublished,_ so the preprint probably exists but is unpublished.